# Why does Android only show the last Activity when using a for-loop?

Tags: java, android

Perhaps I'm not used to the Android development, but when I look, I expect everything to be done in order. When one activity finishes, the next starts. However, it seems that my code doesn't work that way. Take the following code for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){            
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Game.this.getBaseContext(), NextScreen.class);
   myIntent.putExtra("something", i);
   myIntent.putExtra("Opp", oppList.get(i).toString());
   startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
```

It doesn't display activity one, wait for you to do what you do in that screen, then come back for the second activity. It immediately displays the third activity. If I click on the back button on my android emulator, it will show me activity two... and if I click back again, it will show me activity one... so it just kind of rapid-fires these activities onto the screen without waiting for you to do what you do in these activities. I'm sure I'm not the first person that's wanted to do something like this. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? How do you work around this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Activities execute asynchronously. One way to serialize this is to chain the activites in your `onActivityResult` method. Pass to each (sub)activity an activity number, starting with `0` and have the sub-activity return it as part of the result. Your `onActivityResult` logic can deal with the response, then examine the activity number and fire the next activity (if there is one).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are telling me to try. The objective is to iterate through a number of activities. I'm not sure in your statement where I would define the number of times through the loop (as it will change as the game evolves). Would it be defined in the Activity that I'm launching multiple times? Would this be some kind of recursive entity?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can queue up pages like this in 1 handy function. You'd be better off having a function `nextPage` which takes the current activity have moves the user to the next activity. This could be called everytime the user is ready to proceed to the next page (triggered by a button press or something).

Or just start the next activity on the button press directly